# pattern finding in a string python

Tags: python, pattern-matching

I try to create a modified LZW which will find patterns of words inside a string. My problem is that 1st element is '' and last is not checked if it is in the list. I saw the  pseudo-code from here : https://www.cs.duke.edu/csed/curious/compression/lzw.html . Here is my script for compression:

```
string = 'this is a test a test this is pokemon'
diction = []
x = ""
count = 0
for c in string.split():
      print (c)
      print (x)
      #x = x + " " + c 
      if x in diction:
            x += " " + c
            #print("debug")
      else:
            #print(x)
            diction.append(x)
            x = c
            count +=1
            #print(count)

print (diction)
```

I tried to fix the 2nd problem by 'appending' a random word to the end of the string but I don't think that's the best solution.

For the 1st problem I tried just to define the variable "x" as str or None but I get this < class 'str' > inside the list.

Answer (score 0):

The link deals with character and splitting a string will give an array of words. 
In order to get not an empty string in the dictionary and parsing the last element.

```
string = 'this is a test a test this is pokemon'
diction = []
x = ""
count = 0
for c in string.split():
      print (c)
      if x+" "+c in diction:
            x += " " + c
      else:
            diction.append(x+" "+c)
            x = c
            count +=1

print (diction)
```

But perhaps you would like something like :

```
string = 'this is a test a test this is pokemon'
diction = []
x = ""
count = 0
for c in string:
      print (c)
      if x+c in diction:
            x += c
      else:
            diction.append(x+c)
            x = c
            count +=1

print (diction)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the code pretends, but to fix the issues that you mentioned I think you could do this:

```
string = 'this is a test a test this is pokemon'
diction = []
x = None
count = 0
for c in string.split():
    if x in diction:
        x += " " + c
    else:
        if x: diction.append(x)
        x = c
        count += 1

if not x in diction: diction.append(x)

print (diction)
```

The output for that code would be:

```
['this', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'a test', 'this is', 'pokemon']
```